# How can I get "Unlock private key" dialog (gui) with more than only insert password in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, password, xfce, configuration, keyrings

In Xubuntu 17.04 with XFCE interface, when I am in terminal app, I only get a cli interface asking:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I remember that in Ubuntu, when I was in terminal it displays a gui interface asking password to unlock private keys with more options than only insert password.

I try gnome-ask-password in Xubuntu but only ask password without extra options.

How do I get "**Unlock private key**" dialog (gui) in Xubuntu similar to this:

[image]

I want a gui prompt and with extra options like:

- Automatically unlock
- Lock .. when I log out

The gui prompt can be different but with similar options.

**Note to make this question clear**

How to configure a gui interface in Xubuntu with details like image:
    - Automatically unlock this keyring whenever I'm logged in
    - Lock this keyring when I log out

**Someone knows what are the packages that I must install to have gui like image?**

Comment: That's odd. What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX kill -s 0 $SSH_AGENT_PID && echo success`?

Comment: Ok. Looks like a typo in the previous command then.

Comment: Do you have the package `gnome-keyring` installed? What's the output of `pidof gnome-keyring-daemon`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57967/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-diogo-gomes).